# Redirection don't work due to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

In my project, I use a `dropdown menu` to redirect to different places according to the selection. Here is my code.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="color-4">
        <div class="container">
            <section>
                <label class="select-label">Duration</label>
                <select onchange="window.location.href=this.value" class="cs-select cs-skin-slide">
                    <option value="http://127.0.0.1:9763/Kampana-Web/chart/acceleration/24" data-class="icon-camera">24 Hours</option>
                    <option value="http://127.0.0.1:9763/Kampana-Web/chart/acceleration/7" data-class="icon-camera">Last week</option>
                    <option value="http://127.0.0.1:9763/Kampana-Web/chart/acceleration/30" data-class="icon-camera">Last Month</option>
                    <option value="http://127.0.0.1:9763/Kampana-Web/chart/acceleration/90" data-class="icon-camera">Last 3 Months</option>

                </select>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

        <script>
            (function() {
                    [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( 'select.cs-select' ) ).forEach( function(el) {    
                        new SelectFx(el);
                    } );
                })();
        </script>
```

The issue is, redirection do not work with this javascript function. This function is must need one to maintain the functionality and all css support in `dropdown menu`. 
How can I enable redirection with this javascript function?

Here is SelectFx code

```
( function( window ) {

    'use strict';

    /**
     * based on from https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll/blob/master/jquery.nicescroll.js
     */
    function hasParent( e, p ) {
        if (!e) return false;
        var el = e.target||e.srcElement||e||false;
        while (el && el != p) {
            el = el.parentNode||false;
        }
        return (el!==false);
    };

    /**
     * extend obj function
     */
    function extend( a, b ) {
        for( var key in b ) { 
            if( b.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
                a[key] = b[key];
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    /**
     * SelectFx function
     */
    function SelectFx( el, options ) {  
        this.el = el;
        this.options = extend( {}, this.options );
        extend( this.options, options );
        this._init();
    }

    /**
     * SelectFx options
     */
    SelectFx.prototype.options = {
        // if true all the links will open in a new tab.
        // if we want to be redirected when we click an option, we need to define a data-link attr on the option of the native select element
        newTab : true,
        // when opening the select element, the default placeholder (if any) is shown
        stickyPlaceholder : true,
        // callback when changing the value
        onChange : function( val ) { return false; }
    }

    /**
     * init function
     * initialize and cache some vars
     */
    SelectFx.prototype._init = function() {
        // check if we are using a placeholder for the native select box
        // we assume the placeholder is disabled and selected by default
        var selectedOpt = this.el.querySelector( 'option[selected]' );
        this.hasDefaultPlaceholder = selectedOpt && selectedOpt.disabled;

        // get selected option (either the first option with attr selected or just the first option)
        this.selectedOpt = selectedOpt || this.el.querySelector( 'option' );

        // create structure
        this._createSelectEl();

        // all options
        this.selOpts = [].slice.call( this.selEl.querySelectorAll( 'li[data-option]' ) );

        // total options
        this.selOptsCount = this.selOpts.length;

        // current index
        this.current = this.selOpts.indexOf( this.selEl.querySelector( 'li.cs-selected' ) ) || -1;

        // placeholder elem
        this.selPlaceholder = this.selEl.querySelector( 'span.cs-placeholder' );

        // init events
        this._initEvents();
    }

    /**
     * creates the structure for the select element
     */
    SelectFx.prototype._createSelectEl = function() {
        var self = this, options = '', createOptionHTML = function(el) {
            var optclass = '', classes = '', link = '';

            if( el.selectedOpt && !this.foundSelected && !this.hasDefaultPlaceholder ) {
                classes += 'cs-selected ';
                this.foundSelected = true;
            }
            // extra classes
            if( el.getAttribute( 'data-class' ) ) {
                classes += el.getAttribute( 'data-class' );
            }
            // link options
            if( el.getAttribute( 'data-link' ) ) {
                link = 'data-link=' + el.getAttribute( 'data-link' );
            }

            if( classes !== '' ) {
                optclass = 'class="' + classes + '" ';
            }

            return '<li ' + optclass + link + ' data-option data-value="' + el.value + '"><span>' + el.textContent + '</span></li>';
        };

        [].slice.call( this.el.children ).forEach( function(el) {
            if( el.disabled ) { return; }

            var tag = el.tagName.toLowerCase();

            if( tag === 'option' ) {
                options += createOptionHTML(el);
            }
            else if( tag === 'optgroup' ) {
                options += '<li class="cs-optgroup"><span>' + el.label + '</span><ul>';
                [].slice.call( el.children ).forEach( function(opt) {
                    options += createOptionHTML(opt);
                } )
                options += '</ul></li>';
            }
        } );

        var opts_el = '<div class="cs-options"><ul>' + options + '</ul></div>';
        this.selEl = document.createElement( 'div' );
        this.selEl.className = this.el.className;
        this.selEl.tabIndex = this.el.tabIndex;
        this.selEl.innerHTML = '<span class="cs-placeholder">' + this.selectedOpt.textContent + '</span>' + opts_el;
        this.el.parentNode.appendChild( this.selEl );
        this.selEl.appendChild( this.el );
    }

    /**
     * initialize the events
     */
    SelectFx.prototype._initEvents = function() {
        var self = this;

        // open/close select
        this.selPlaceholder.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
            self._toggleSelect();
        } );

        // clicking the options
        this.selOpts.forEach( function(opt, idx) {
            opt.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
                self.current = idx;
                self._changeOption();
                // close select elem
                self._toggleSelect();
            } );
        } );

        // close the select element if the target it´s not the select element or one of its descendants..
        document.addEventListener( 'click', function(ev) {
            var target = ev.target;
            if( self._isOpen() && target !== self.selEl && !hasParent( target, self.selEl ) ) {
                self._toggleSelect();
            }
        } );

        // keyboard navigation events
        this.selEl.addEventListener( 'keydown', function( ev ) {
            var keyCode = ev.keyCode || ev.which;

            switch (keyCode) {
                // up key
                case 38:
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    self._navigateOpts('prev');
                    break;
                // down key
                case 40:
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    self._navigateOpts('next');
                    break;
                // space key
                case 32:
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    if( self._isOpen() && typeof self.preSelCurrent != 'undefined' && self.preSelCurrent !== -1 ) {
                        self._changeOption();
                    }
                    self._toggleSelect();
                    break;
                // enter key
                case 13:
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    if( self._isOpen() && typeof self.preSelCurrent != 'undefined' && self.preSelCurrent !== -1 ) {
                        self._changeOption();
                        self._toggleSelect();
                    }
                    break;
                // esc key
                case 27:
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    if( self._isOpen() ) {
                        self._toggleSelect();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        } );
    }

    /**
     * navigate with up/dpwn keys
     */
    SelectFx.prototype._navigateOpts = function(dir) {
        if( !this._isOpen() ) {
            this._toggleSelect();
        }

        var tmpcurrent = typeof this.preSelCurrent != 'undefined' && this.preSelCurrent !== -1 ? this.preSelCurrent : this.current;

        if( dir === 'prev' && tmpcurrent > 0 || dir === 'next' && tmpcurrent < this.selOptsCount - 1 ) {
            // save pre selected current - if we click on option, or press enter, or press space this is going to be the index of the current option
            this.preSelCurrent = dir === 'next' ? tmpcurrent + 1 : tmpcurrent - 1;
            // remove focus class if any..
            this._removeFocus();
            // add class focus - track which option we are navigating
            classie.add( this.selOpts[this.preSelCurrent], 'cs-focus' );
        }
    }

    /**
     * open/close select
     * when opened show the default placeholder if any
     */
    SelectFx.prototype._toggleSelect = function() {
        // remove focus class if any..
        this._removeFocus();

        if( this._isOpen() ) {
            if( this.current !== -1 ) {
                // update placeholder text
                this.selPlaceholder.textContent = this.selOpts[ this.current ].textContent;
            }
            classie.remove( this.selEl, 'cs-active' );
        }
        else {
            if( this.hasDefaultPlaceholder && this.options.stickyPlaceholder ) {
                // everytime we open we wanna see the default placeholder text
                this.selPlaceholder.textContent = this.selectedOpt.textContent;
            }
            classie.add( this.selEl, 'cs-active' );
        }
    }

    /**
     * change option - the new value is set
     */
    SelectFx.prototype._changeOption = function() {
        // if pre selected current (if we navigate with the keyboard)...
        if( typeof this.preSelCurrent != 'undefined' && this.preSelCurrent !== -1 ) {
            this.current = this.preSelCurrent;
            this.preSelCurrent = -1;
        }

        // current option
        var opt = this.selOpts[ this.current ];

        // update current selected value
        this.selPlaceholder.textContent = opt.textContent;

        // change native select element´s value
        this.el.value = opt.getAttribute( 'data-value' );

        // remove class cs-selected from old selected option and add it to current selected option
        var oldOpt = this.selEl.querySelector( 'li.cs-selected' );
        if( oldOpt ) {
            classie.remove( oldOpt, 'cs-selected' );
        }
        classie.add( opt, 'cs-selected' );

        // if there´s a link defined
        if( opt.getAttribute( 'data-link' ) ) {
            // open in new tab?
            if( this.options.newTab ) {
                window.open( opt.getAttribute( 'data-link' ), '_blank' );
            }
            else {
                window.location = opt.getAttribute( 'data-link' );
            }
        }

        // callback
        this.options.onChange( this.el.value );
    }

    /**
     * returns true if select element is opened
     */
    SelectFx.prototype._isOpen = function(opt) {
        return classie.has( this.selEl, 'cs-active' );
    }

    /**
     * removes the focus class from the option
     */
    SelectFx.prototype._removeFocus = function(opt) {
        var focusEl = this.selEl.querySelector( 'li.cs-focus' )
        if( focusEl ) {
            classie.remove( focusEl, 'cs-focus' );
        }
    }

    /**
     * add to global namespace
     */
    window.SelectFx = SelectFx;

} )( window );
```

Comment: What plugin is `SelectFx`?

Comment: *SelectFx* is a javascript library.

Comment: I can't save my JSFiddle at the moment - JSFiddle seems to completely break with the SelectFx code present, but the code below appears to work with `SelectFX`. Please try the change and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As you are have tagged this question with `jQuery` you can simplify your existing code to the following:

```
$(function () {  // Shortcut for $(document).ready(){...}
    $('select.cs-select').each(function () {
        new SelectFx(this);
    });
});
```

*Without info on `SelectFx` I afraid can't make you a working example, but hopefully this will help*